# Apply styles to MTableEditRow action component

Tags: material-table

I'm trying to apply styling to MTableEditRow actions component which comes from MUI. I've tried doing it with actionCellStyle and overriding action components but they do not apply to that specific element. The only solution which worked for me so far is using styled components (or styled MUI API) like so :

```
const StyledEditRow = styled(MTableEditRow)({
    verticalAlign: "top",
    height: "110px",
    "& .MuiTableCell-root": { padding: "20px 5px !important" }
})
```

I would like to avoid using `!important` to override the style applied in the component if at all possible. It's a little bit weird that `actionsCellStyle` works only for one set of actions, or is there something I'm missing? Any help would be great!